# Import classes from shared object into a specific namespace

Tags: c++, gcc, elf

I have a compiled ELF file, libfoo.so, that exports some class methods, like:

```cpp
struct Bar {
   void f();
   void g();
};
```

I know the exact declaration of these classes, but the definition is compiled into the .so. I'm using the same compiler (gcc >= 7) as the .so, so the name mangling and ABI match. This means that if I add the above declaration to my code, I'll be able to call the methods implemented in libfoo.so directly.

However, I don't want to pollute my namespace with toplevel libfoo stuff (and I don't control libfoo source). So I'd like to declare `struct Bar` inside `namespace foo {}`.  Now, once I do that, the name mangling no longer matches and the loader will not be able to find the functions in question.

I do not want to write thunks for all of them as a) there's thousands and b) it causes issues with virtual functions and destructors.

I'm thinking of using `objcopy` and renaming all exported symbols in libfoo.so, but hoping there's a better solution here.

Both libfoo and my code are using C++14 (can be moved to C++17) and gcc 7 (can be moved to later). Compiled for 64bit ELF on Linux.

Comment: compiled code will become completely corrupted, not trustful and//or unstable. Not impossible but I think that you have to approach differently

Comment: Can you elaborate @memosdp ? The compiled libfoo.so should not care about what the other parts of the executable do, or what its exported symbols are named. It's entirely standalone and can function even with 99% of the symbols stripped completely.

Comment: Still it is a library and not only this, it is a `so` which means `shared object`. How are you going to refactor the relocations? I think you have to dive more into `elflib` to do this and not simply `objcopy`

Comment: I wouldn't be changing the relocations at all. The objcopy would just _rename_ the symbols as they're seen _externally_. Internally, the lib is using relative offsets which remain unchanged. All the code of the lib remains the same, just symbol names (i.e. output of `nm`) gets a bit more decorated - but this is never used by the lib itself, it's only meant for consumers of the lib (and debuggers, printing stack traces, etc)

Comment: I didn't say a thing about the symbols and I will stay with this. Relocations don't have to do with the symbols but with the memory address, but I think you are convinced somehow that there will not be a problem if you do this. From my side I don't have something better to give you but when you see difficulties by doing this let me know, maybe ill be here around to help you

Comment: I still don't understand what relocations have to do with anything here, and more importantly, I don't understand _how_ things could break in the way you're saying. I just made a small test with renaming of the symbols and saw no issues..

Comment: Both the problem and solution very much repesents the spirit of C++. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a lot more complex than expected, but I did manage. If `libfoo.so` has the function `Bar::f()` (mangled as `_ZN3Bar1fEv`), and I want to define `foo::Bar::f()` (`_ZN3foo3Bar1fEv`), I first need to find the relative offset of the function in libfoo.so. With `nm` you get something like:

```
0000000000abcd00 T _ZN3Bar1fEv
```

I have a script that parses this output, and generates assembly code like this:

```
; Export start of the translation space
.global START
START:
    nop

.global _ZN3foo3Bar1fEv ; Desired target name
_ZN3foo3Bar1fEv:
    movq $0x0000abcd12345678, %rax ; arbitrary constant
    addq $0xabcd00, %rax ; offset from libfoo
    pushq %rax
    ret

; same for every other needed symbol

; Export end of the translation space
.global END
END:
    nop
```

This defines a "naked" function with the desired name, which adds an arbitrary constant to the offset and jumps to it. The extra jump is a perf hit I can live with.

The arbitrary constant is needed to deal with ASLR - the `0xabcd00` is the base offset, but when libfoo.so is loaded to some base address (e.g. `0x04000000`) the actual address of the function (i.e. if you wanted a function pointer) is `0x04abde00`. When generating the asm code, I used a temporary constant that I'll fix up after loading:

```
const uintptr_t offset = 0xabcd00; // Expected offset in libfoo.so
uintptr_t real = (uintptr_t) dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "_ZN3Bar1fEv"); // real address with ASLR
uintptr_t aslr_base = real - offset; // This is the actual base to be applied.

// Search everything between START and END and update the arbitrary constant
extern "C" void START(); extern "C" void END();
uint8_t *p = (uint8_t*)&START;
uint8_t *end = (uint8_t*)&END;
mprotect(ALIGN_TO_PAGE(p), end-p+PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC); // mark the memory as writable
// update all instances of the arbitrary constant
while (p != end)
{
    if (*(uintptr_t*)p == 0x0000abcd12345678)
        *(uintptr_t*)p = aslr_base;
    p++;
}
```

You can then restore the memory protections. The asm can be optimized to not use `rax` by doing calculations using just `push` and `mov` with indirect addressing using `rsp`, but this works for my case.

---

## What doesn't work

- `objcopy` allows redefining or injecting *static* symbols, but has no support for editing dynamic symbol table. None of the tools I found do either.
- Linker scripts allow defining aliases (`PROVIDE(alias = real)`), but only if the target is defined at the time of linking; you cannot create an alias to a dynamic symbol.
- Sourcing the ASLR offset from a global variable does not work - The linker kept asking that all code be compiled with `-fPIC`, which it was. This would have removed the need to modify the code.